# How to avoid Google-Cloud-Dataflow Import Error when using it inside Luigi

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, luigi

I have multiple processes which are dependent on each other. I am using Luigi to manage these dependencies. Since there are multiple processes, I have made package of each of the process. I.e All the relevant files of the process are in a folder having an init file. I am using one Luigi task which looks into its dependency and executes which ever process that are required to be completed for that task to run.

In one of those tasks is a dataflow job. When i call that dataflow job it raises an import error,

**ImportError: No module named TaskBQ2DS.TaskBQ2DS**

```
 (38c7b56641434bc6): Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
     work_executor.execute()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
     op.start()
   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 294, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10607)
     def start(self):
   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 295, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10501)
     with self.scoped_start_state:
   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 300, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:9702)
     pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 225, in loads
     return dill.loads(s)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads
     return load(file)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load
     obj = pik.load()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
     dispatch[key](self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
     klass = self.find_class(module, name)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class
     return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
     __import__(module)
 ImportError: No module named TaskBQ2DS.TaskBQ2DS
```

Basically, that file has the dataflow pipes defined in it. I know the error is caused since dataflow is not able to understand The environment around the dataflow job, which is the luigi task, and I think that can be made aware of it using either `requirements` or `setup` file. But It is still confusing.

When I use `os` module to execute that task using command line, it works properly, but when I import that module and run it, it throws that error

**My question is**

**What is the right way** of calling that dataflow job?

Should I execute it using the `os` module by calling it through a bash command ?

or

Should I call it by importing the module in the Luigi task and calling the function which will run the dataflow job.

If I should do it using the latter method, then how do i solve that error?
I know about the `requirements file`, the `setup file` that we can provide to dataflow job for our personalised virtual environment.
But I am confused about how to do it right way.

I hope was able to convey my question rightly and not make it an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I can update the question with more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error and problem description, it sounds like your Luigi scheduler is running from a different Python environment/interpreter than the one used when calling a new process via `os` or `subprocess`

It's been a while since I've used Luigi, but if your Luigi `task` dependency resolution involves inspection of a `target` that is defined in one of these packages, you generally want to have the `task` and `target` be importable and natively callable by your master task; this enables the graph of the originally called master task to be more easily seen against its Luigi `task` dependences, which may also have unsatisfied dependencies of their own.

You can address this by ensuring that all of your package requirements are installed and available to the same Python interpreter running your Luigi scheduler.